# Send message to Azure ServiceBus when items have changed in a Sharepoint List

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azureservicebus

I'd like to send message to an Azure ServiceBus queue when some items have changed inside a SharePoint list. When you upload/delete a file, I need to create an event that enqueue a message in Azure Service Bus with the content of the file and the id. I don't know how to create an event that do that, Can someone point to me some articles, tutorial to start.

Comment: You question is very unclear.. On the SP side, you send a message to a servicebus queue, topic, evenhub ? And then what do you try to achieve ? Connect to the servicebus entity ?

Comment: I edited the question, the fact is that I thought that sharepoint send the message automatically, I am new with this services, and now what I need is to know how to create an event that send a message to service bus every time some change ocurrs.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint are you using ? what your are looking is an event receiver: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx. Every time a new item is added or updated, it will trigger your code so that you can send a message to the servicebus queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for event receiver:

- [How to: Create an Event Receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)

> By creating event receivers, you can respond when a user interacts with SharePoint items such as lists or list items. For example, the code in an event receiver can be triggered when a user changes the calendar or deletes a name from a contacts list.

Sample code from the documentation:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.ListItem["Patient Name"] = "Scott Brown";
    properties.ListItem.Update();
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
}
```

Now you need to change this code to send message to a servicebus queue:
[Get started with Service Bus Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues/)

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    var connectionString = "<Your connection string>";
    var queueName = "<Your queue name>";
    var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
    var message = new BrokeredMessage("This is a test message!");

    client.Send(message);

    base.ItemAdded(properties);
}
```

If you need to send the content of the file, just keep in mind tihs:

> Service Bus queues support a maximum message size of 256 Kb (the header, which includes the standard and custom application properties, can have a maximum size of 64 Kb).

So you may need to store your file into a blob storage and just send a message to the queue with the id of the create blob also.

- [Get started with Azure Blob storage using .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)